# WordPress e Woocommerce - WC_Order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Preciso de ajuda num projeto. 
Eu desenvolvi um site totalmente personalizado no WordPress. Total as páginas são padronizadas, mas o usuário só pode ter acesso às páginas se tiver produto ativo. Então eu preciso configurar o ambiente dele no momento da compra, ou seja, no 
`woocommerce_is_order_received_page`.

Pois bem... percebi que na página de pagamento bem sucedido, `woocommerce_is_order_received_page`, tem um a chave do pedido em `$_GET['key']`, e por meio deste dado eu consigo **pegar parcialmente** todos os dados.

```
<?php $data_order = wc_get_order(wc_get_order_id_by_order_key($_GET['key'])); ?>
```

Eis a questão... os dados que eu preciso estão encapsulados dentro de métodos privados e eu não consigo usá-los, somente visualizar.
Como faço para pegar o item comprado, bem como os outros dados privados?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Eu pesquisei um pouco mais a fundo e descobri que eu estva bem perto da solução do problema. Encontrei um comentário bem interessante que me mostrou que o que faltava era definir o global $wpdb antes. E também usar o foreach para extrair os item privado (eu não entendi isso plenamente, mas funcionou). E então ficou assim:

```
// Take the info order
// Pega informações do pedido
global $wpdb;
$ws_order = new WC_Order( wc_get_order_id_by_order_key($_GET['key']) );
$ws_items = $ws_order->get_items();  

// This foreach retur a string of data order: $item_id {"string items": value}
// Este foreach serve para pegar o dados do peido no formato string
foreach ($ws_items as $key => $product ) {
    $ws_data_items = $key . $product;
}
```

Você poderá fazer um teste para ver a saída: `var_dump($ws_data_items);`
No meu caso, a saída foi a seguinte: 
**string(222)**"13{"id":13,"order_id":117,"name":"Mensal",**"product_id":116**,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"29.9","subtotal_tax":"0","total":"29.9","total_tax":"0","taxes":{"total":[],"subtotal":[]},"meta_data":[]}"

Até aqui você já tem os dado do pedido, e com eles poderá fazer o que quiser.
Mas... para minha resposta ficar completa, vou mostrar o que precisei fazer para pegar a **categoria do item** do pedido, vejam:
*OBS: com certeza deve ter um jeito mais fácil de fazer isso, mas me parece que não há esta informação no nosso grande amigo Google, muito menos na documentação do Woocommerce. Então... isso é que tem pra hoje... hehe*
Primeiramente, note que **o resultado é uma string** com chave e valor (eu também não entendi porque é uma string e não um array). Isso não é nenhum pouco legal, porque será preciso limpar os dados inúteis;  eu só quero o id do product que (me refiro ao id do post_type=product), **especificamente neste caso é 116**.

Vamos usar a funções `str_replace` e `strstr()` do PHP. Se eu explicar como funciona cada uma delas, isso vai ficar muito longo, etão veja a explicação delas em php.net [[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) e [strstr]](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php):

```
$ws_only_id_item = str_replace(array(':'), '', strstr(strstr(strstr($ws_data_items, 'product_id'), ',', true), ':'));
```

Depois disso, eu tenho o número **116 armazenado em `$ws_only_id_item`**.
Com esta informação é só pegar a categoria com WP_Term class da seguinte forma.

```
// isso pega o nome da cateria 
// Note que se você tiver mais de uma categoria no produto, é preciso fazer um foreach
// No meu caso, sempre terá apenas uma categoria então eu decidi usar [0]
$ws_array_terms = get_the_terms ( $ws_only_id_item, 'product_cat' );
$ws_obj_cat = $ws_array_terms[0];
echo $ws_obj_cat->name;
```